# Curl request post with proxy

Tags: curl, proxy, libcurl

I make a proxy request post with Curl,

My code:

```
curl -x http://188.213.171.143:81 -s --data "user=$1&" https://api.url.com/api/info?api_key=7236472he728che7328e
```

I tried many servers but none worked,
is there a problem in my code?

Comment: You need to tell us much more details. Exactly how didn't it work, what errors did it report or what happened?

Comment: I get 400 BAD request

Comment: (that should be edited into the question) If a proxy responds with a 400 to a CONNECT, I'd say it sounds just like a broken proxy/setup.